# unison across shared drive on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, unison

I have a shared drive at \192.168.1.110
My unison is setup to copy from

```
C:\mydata 
to
\\192.168.1.110\mydata
```

I can access \192.168.1.110\mydata however when I try from the command prompt unison tells me 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.', it doesn't have the authentification information that I specified from the explorer window.
How can I specify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just right click on 'My PC' (or 'Computer' in Windows 7) icon on the desktop and select 'connect to a network drive' or 'Map network drive', or click 'Start->Computer->Map network drive' or press ALT Key and click 'Tools->Map Network drive' in any explorer window, and type `\\192.168.1.110\mydata` and assign an unused drive letter, for example `Z:`.

Now you you have mounted a virtual drive which works as any other drive in windows so you don't have to bother about logins and network issues. Just setup your program to copy from `C:\mydata` to `Z:\` or whatever letter you assign to your network drive.